# What font is this (pdf)?

Tags: fonts

I want to know what kind of font is this :

http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M55a.02/pdflatex/top5.pdf

Thanks.

Comment: Computer Modern. Type1. Embedded subsets. Your PDF viewer will tell you this. Just look for something like File > Properties > Fonts.